Automating Google Analytics Data Extraction to Oracle APEX Database
I'm looking to automate the extraction of Google Analytics data into an Oracle APEX database table without user interaction. I've successfully tested the API (POST https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/{property=properties/*}:runReport) using the Google-provided testing page with my Gmail account.
However, I'm unsure about the authentication process for automating this data extraction. Could anyone guide me on how to authenticate and automate this process?
Thanks in advance for your help!

It's possible, but not very simple.
From google side:
You need Enable the Google Analytics Data API, create a service account and Grant Access to the Google Analytics Property.
From Oracle side:
Create a python script that Authenticate with the API Using Service Account, then Insert Data into Oracle APEX Database.
After this, you can schedule on crontab.
Hope it helps.
